# Nested sub tag resultset xml T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm not an expert for XML query... but I need only little step to my goal.

With the query below.

I got a problem in EANs tag with the sub tag EAN.

```
SELECT 
    ExternalId,  
    [Name],
    [Description],
    BrandExternalId,
    CategoryExternalId,
    ProductPageUrl,
    ImageUrl,    
    (SELECT ManufacturerPartNumber
     FOR XML PATH('ManufacturerPartNumbers'), TYPE),
    (SELECT b.EAN_Single as EAN  
     FROM #SP b 
     WHERE (ff.ExternalId = b.codart)  
     FOR XML PATH('EANs'), TYPE)
FROM 
    Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_00 ff with (nolock) 
WHERE 
    [ExternalId] IN (100001023)
FOR XML PATH ('Product'), ROOT('Products');
```

I get this result:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ExternalId>100001023</ExternalId>
        <Name>Carta Lucida Adesiva Photo Stickers PS-101</Name>
        <Description>Carta lucida Photo Stickers.</Description>
        <BrandExternalId>CANON</BrandExternalId>
        <CategoryExternalId>10132</CategoryExternalId>
        <ManufacturerPartNumbers>
            <ManufacturerPartNumber>0001C001</ManufacturerPartNumber>
        </ManufacturerPartNumbers>
        <EANs>
            <EAN>0138030471030</EAN>
        </EANs>
        <EANs>
            <EAN>5051749491517</EAN>
        </EANs>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

but I need the result to look like this:

```
<EANs>
    <EAN>0138030471030</EAN>
    <EAN>5051749491517</EAN>
</EANs>
```

Can someone help me with this?

THANKS Alen, Italy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as the subquery.

```
 (SELECT b.EAN_Single as EAN  
     FROM #SP b 
     WHERE (ff.ExternalId = b.codart)  
     FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('EANS'), TYPE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Perfect! ALEN